# Adding a 1 to a column in a text file with open function

Tags: perl

I have a text file that I am trying to adjust the second column by adding 1 to it. I have tried adjusting the code we practiced in class, but it is not going so well. This is what my current code looks like. If possible, I would like to use the `open` function.

```
use strict; use warnings;
open(my $in, '<first5.txt') or die ("Cannot execute");
open(my $out, '>first5.txt') or die ("Cannot execute");
while(<$in>){
    chomp ($in);
    my@input = split("\t", $in);
    print("New chromosome position:",$input[1]+1, "\n");
}
close $in;
close $out;
```

```
This is the original first5.txt
chr10   50005   50005   CHH:0   0   +
chr10   50006   50006   CHH:0   0   +
chr10   50013   50013   CHH:0   0   +
chr10   50014   50014   CHH:0   0   +
chr10   50021   50021   CHH:0   0   +

This is my desired outcome
chr10   50006   50005   CHH:0   0   +
chr10   50007   50006   CHH:0   0   +
chr10   50014   50013   CHH:0   0   +
chr10   50015   50014   CHH:0   0   +
chr10   50022   50021   CHH:0   0   +
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are still classes in which `perl` is taught?!

Comment: Use the 3 argument form of open, and include the path and `$!` in the error message.  `open(my $in, '<', 'first5.txt') or die ("first5.txt: $!");`

Answer (score 4):

`while(<$in>)` reads a line into `$_` - so `chomp; my @input = split/\t/;` is what you should do. You should however not open the same file for input and output at the same time. That will truncate the file (on Posix) or fail (on Windows).

Here are the suggested adjustments:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $inputfile = 'first5.txt';
my $outputfile = 'first5.TMP';            # write to a temporary file

open(my $in, '<', $inputfile) or die ("Cannot open $inputfile: $!");
open(my $out, '>', $outputfile) or die ("Cannot open $outputfile: $!");

while(<$in>) {                            # read a line into $_
    chomp;                                # chomp $_
    my @input = split/\t/;                # split $_ on \t
    ++$input[1];                          # add 1 to col 1
    print $out join("\t", @input) . "\n"; # print result to outputfile
}

close $in;
close $out;

rename $outputfile, $inputfile;           # move the temporary into place
```

Answer (score 3):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in, '<', 'first5.txt' or die $!;
open my $out, '>', 'first5.new' or die $!;
while (<$in>) {
    chomp;
    my @columns = split /\t/;
    ++$columns[1];
    print {$out} join "\t", @columns;
    print {$out} "\n";
}
close $out;
rename 'first5.new', 'first5.txt' or die $!;
```

The changes I made:

- Use the 3 argument version of open. It's safer when using variable names.
- Include the reason why the open failed ($!) in the error message.
- Don't open the same file for input and output.
- Don't chomp the handle.
- Use better variable names.
- You can use ++ to increment a variable.
- The first argument to [split](http://p3rl.org/split) is a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already pointed out the problems with reading and writing to the same file simultaneously.

I just wanted to point out that your current code never actually writes to the output file. Where you have:

```
print("New chromosome position:",$input[1]+1, "\n");
```

You probably wanted:

```
print $out "New chromosome position:",$input[1]+1, "\n";
```